# Open multiple files in tabs from Explore mode

Tags: netrw, tabbed-user-interface, multiple-files

While navigating file system in `:Explore` mode, is it possible to select and open multiple files, each in a new tab?

**Edit:**

I ended up using a function proposed by *Jair López*, because it works pretty much as I envisioned it, although *statox* provided a good explanation for built-in netrw mechanics.

For consistency, I also added a normal mode mapping to make <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> open a new tab, while keeping netrw tab in focus. It simplifies opening tabs for multiple files that aren't listed consecutively.

```
autocmd Filetype netrw nmap <buffer> <silent> TT VT
```

Comment: Right, this mapping worked fine with previous version of a function, which didn't have a mandatory argument. I changed it to your variant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's Vim do it for you. You can put the following code at the end of your 
`vimrc` file:

```
function! NetrwOpenMultiTab(current_line,...) range
   " Get the number of lines.
   let n_lines =  a:lastline - a:firstline + 1

   " This is the command to be built up.
   let command = "normal "

   " Iterator.
   let i = 1

   " Virtually iterate over each line and build the command.
   while i < n_lines
      let command .= "tgT:" . ( a:firstline + i ) . "\<CR>:+tabmove\<CR>"
      let i += 1
   endwhile
   let command .= "tgT"

   " Restore the Explore tab position.
   if i != 1
      let command .= ":tabmove -" . ( n_lines - 1 ) . "\<CR>"
   endif

   " Restore the previous cursor line.
   let command .= ":" . a:current_line  . "\<CR>"

   " Check function arguments
   if a:0 > 0
      if a:1 > 0 && a:1 <= n_lines
         " The current tab is for the nth file.
         let command .= ( tabpagenr() + a:1 ) . "gt"
      else
         " The current tab is for the last selected file.
         let command .= (tabpagenr() + n_lines) . "gt"
      endif
   endif
   " The current tab is for the Explore tab by default.

   " Execute the custom command.
   execute command
endfunction

" Define mappings.
augroup NetrwOpenMultiTabGroup
   autocmd!
   autocmd Filetype netrw vnoremap <buffer> <silent> <expr> t ":call NetrwOpenMultiTab(" . line(".") . "," . "v:count)\<CR>"
   autocmd Filetype netrw vnoremap <buffer> <silent> <expr> T ":call NetrwOpenMultiTab(" . line(".") . "," . (( v:count == 0) ? '' : v:count) . ")\<CR>"
augroup END
```

Restart Vim and then you can:

1. Open Netrw (e.g., with `:Explore`)
2. Move the cursor to the first file.
3. Enter Line-wise Visual mode by hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>
4. Hit <kbd>J</kbd> (That's not <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>, just in case)
   as much as you need to.
5. Hit <kbd>T</kbd>

### Advantages

- You don't need to add any plugin
- It doesn't stuff the arglist
- You'll preserve the order of the buffer list and tabs
- You can choose which tab will be the current one by using or not using a
  count in the mapping.

### Explanation

There's a lot going on here so if you're in doubt, just let me know. Let's 
say the directory you open with `:Explore` is as follows:

```
../
./
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
```

And the cursor is on file `a.txt` and next, you press 
<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> and move the cursor to the line with `d.txt`.
You can hit:

- <kbd>T</kbd> to open each file in a tab and select the file `d.txt` as the 
  current tab
- <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to open each file in a tab and select the file `a.txt` as the
  current tab
- <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to open each file in a tab and select the file `b.txt` as the
  current tab
- And so on

Or you can hit:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> to open each file in a tab and keep the
  current tab.
- <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> to do the same as <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>
- <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> to do the same as <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

The differences between <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> and <kbd>T</kbd> are:

- <kbd>T</kbd> select the last selected file as the current tab by default
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> keeps the current tab by default

Comment: I like the idea, but currently it doesn't work correctly for me. When I select multiple files with Shift-V and press t, I see a correct number of new tabs opened, but only the first tab is a file (first one in the list), while the rest are just copies of netrw tab.

Comment: I tried to debug this, and with V=15 I found that, for 2 selected files, the following command is executed: "normal tgTj:+tabmove^MtgT:tabmove -2^M3gt". Afterwards, I tried to call it manually. From what I see, the problem is that after first "tgT" the cursor jumps to the top of netrw list (to ".."), and "j" moves it down to ".", which is why rest of the tabs are opened as a copy of current directory.

Comment: I replaced `"tgTj:+tabmove\<CR>"` with `"tgT:" . ( line(".") + i ) . "\<CR>:+tabmove\<CR>"`. Now it seem to work correctly.

Comment: @Thunderbeef Yes, You're right. And you could also avoid the `line(".")` function by adding `a:firstline` instead (see edit).

Comment: One extra thing I hope to achieve is to return the cursor to original line if netrw tab is in the focus at the end (e.g. when using Shift+T).

Comment: Do you know why the same code does not work if I use `normal!` instead of `normal` (to avoid mappings expansion)?

Comment: Because `t` is mapped by Netrw. By the way, what version of Netrw is it?

Comment: I see. Makes sense. My version is `netrw v155`.

Comment: See edit. How about now?

Comment: Thank you. It works.  Though I think this line can be put under `else` clause for `if a:0 > 0`.

Comment: Well, I thought the same thing right off the top of my head, but in my Netrw it also works with `t` out of the box. It also works with `"tgTj:+tabmove\<CR>"` by pressing either `T` or `t`. Maybe you have something in your settings that modifies Netrw's behavior. This Netrw's issue was reported and fixed back in 2011 (see [`vim_user` mailing list archive](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/JzqEBLx6M6A)).

Comment: I found that `":tabmove -" . n_lines` should actually be `":tabmove -" . ( n_lines - 1 )`. Older Vim versions do not report an error if number is higher than tab count, so you can even use `tabmove -999`, while newer ones, along with Neovim, returns `invalid argument`. I also use `a:firstline` instead of `a:current_line`, which is undefined.

Comment: When is number higher than tab count?

Comment: it is equal to tab count, but tabmove needs a number smaller by 1. E.g. if there are 3 tabs, executing `tabmove -2` moves tab to the left completely, while `tabmove -3` results in `invalid argument`.

Comment: I got it, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your code. I have a problem. Please help! There are 6 files in folder, I select all of them using 'Shift-v' and 'j'. Then press 't'. I see the same filename twice in the top. Command ':ls' shows:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2  a   "addon_fingerprint.admin.inc"  line 0
  3  h   "[No Name]"                    line 1
  4  a   "addon_fingerprint.info"       line 0
  5  h   "[No Name]"                    line 1
  6 %a   "addon_fingerprint.install"    line 1
  7 #h   "[No Name]"                    line 1

Comment: Update: Problem appear for 'let g:netrw_liststyle = 1'. For '3' and default works fine.

Answer (score 13):

From [`:h netrw-t`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw%2dt):

```
BROWSING WITH A NEW TAB             netrw-t

Normally one enters a file or directory using the <cr>.  The "t" map
allows one to open a new window holding the new directory listing or file in
a new tab.
```

So in the netrw window simply press <kbd>t</kbd> when your cursor is on the file or on the directory you want to open in the new tab.

---

To do that with multiple files you need to mark them, put them in the arglist and then use the arg list to open the tabs.

To mark a file in a netrw window use <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>.

Once the files are marked put them in the arglist with <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>.

Then simply use `:argdo tabnew`.

**Edit** To reduce the number of keypresses you can add the following line in your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd Filetype netrw nmap <buffer> <F5> ma:argdo tabnew<CR>
```

This is an autocommand which is executed when you open a netrw buffer (`FileType netrw`) and creates a mapping only in this buffer which will put the marked files in the arglist and issue the command `:argdo tabnew`.

With that you can simply mark your files with <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> and use <kbd>F5</kbd> (or another key if you prefer) to open the files in new tabs.

---

See

- [`:h netrw-mf`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw%2dmf)
- [`:h netrw-ma`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw%2dma)
- [`:h :argdo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3aargdo)
- [`:h arglist`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#arglist)

Comment: Thanks. That sure is a lot of work. I was hoping for something like 'Enter Visual mode -> select multiple files -> press "t"'. Also, you a have a typo ('argo').

Comment: @Thunderbeef Thanks for the typo. Now to leverage the number of keypresses I think you could create a mapping which would do the `ma` and `:argdo tabnew` and put the mapping in an autocommand triggered on the `FileType netrw` event.

Comment: @Thunderbeef See my edit for the mapping.

Comment: Thanks. That is certainly more convenient. Though there is still one thing that bothers me: in addition to opening marked files, it also opens empty [No Name] tab, and focuses on it by default. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Nevermind, I just added :q<CR> to the command.

Comment: One more thing I didn't notice immediately: when tabs are opened this way, syntax highlighting is disabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind installing a plugin, you could use [dirvish](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-dirvish).

Once the directory opened, visually select the files (e.g. with `VG`) and press `t` to open in a tab.