# Jump to last position when using vim netrw to open a file

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, autocmd, netrw

I am looking to jump automatically to the last position in any file that I open.

I have in my ~/.vimrc file:

```
autocmd BufReadPost *                                                                                                                                                                                   
  \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \ exe "normal! g`\"" |
  \ endif
```

This works fine if I open a file using the `vim` command.

But if I write `vim .` in a directory to load netrw and use `t` to open a file in a new tab, the cursor appears at the top of the file and not at the last position.

I then have to use `` `" `` to jump to the last position.

Is there any way to jump to the last position when using netrw and `t`?

Thanks.

Comment: Simple answer would be to map `t` in netrw buffer to open the file under cursor in a new tab and do `'"`.

Comment: I had some trouble remapping.

I added to my ~/.vimrc file `autocmd FileType netrw noremap <buffer> t j` just to test, and `t` does get mapped to `j`.

But when I tried to map anything to `t`, e.g., `autocmd FileType netrw noremap <buffer> j t` or even `autocmd FileType netrw noremap <buffer> t t`, nothing happens.

In any case, I found an easy workaround. Just adding to ~/.vimrc `let g:netrw_browse_split = 3` allows me to hit `enter` to open the file in a new tab and jump to the last position.

Comment: Glad it worked. And the reason mapping `j` to `t` wasn't working is because you were using noremap. `t` was already a mapping, you either needed to use `nremap` or, more appropriately, find out what command was netrw-t mapped to and map `j` to that command directly.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, `nremap` did not work, either, but I did instead incorporate this: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13344/open-multiple-files-in-tabs-from-explore-mode. I just added ``\"` to a couple of lines to get `let command .= "t`\"gT:" . ( a:firstline + i ) . "\<CR>:+tabmove\<CR>"` and `let command .= "t`\"gT"`. This does not change the mapping for `t`, but it works well. I might look into the `t` mapping later.